# Where to put user configuration fields for a custom component in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I've built a custom lightning component that is embedded in Record pages, but I can't figure out from documentation how to setup a configuration area for the User to put their data for the component. Can somebody point me in the right directions ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm):

> Use a design resource to control which attributes are exposed to builder tools like the Lightning App Builder, Community Builder, or Cloud Flow Designer. A design resource lives in the same folder as your .cmp resource, and describes the design-time behavior of the Lightning component—information that visual tools need to display the component in a page or app.

Here's the example given in on that page:

```
<design:component label="Hello World">
    <design:attribute name="subject" label="Subject" description="Name of the person you want to greet" />
    <design:attribute name="greeting" label="Greeting" />
</design:component>
```

By following these instructions, users will be able to configure the input data within Lightning App Builder.